# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred 12170. 00000 - "TNS:Connect timeout occurred"

Tags: oracle

I created a database link between two database one in my real machine and the second in my virtual machine using   virtualbox

```
CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK LINK34
  connect to user2 identified by user2
  using '192.168.1.28:1521/XE';
```

bu when i test the database link i get this error ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred
12170. 00000 -  "TNS:Connect timeout occurred"
to note that i can ping to my virtual machine.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: The fact that you can ping the vm only proves there is actually a network path to it.  But ping uses different protocols and ports than does tns.  I'd bet dollars to donuts that your vm has a firewall blocking the connection.  What OS is the vm running?

Comment: i use windows 7

Comment: be sure that the listener is up and listening on the ip you indicated (run lsnrctl stat)

Comment: @gsalem - if that were the case (listener not running or using wrong port), the error would have definitively been ora-12541 - No Listener, not the ora-12170 reported by the OP.

Comment: @nabil - Windows 7 -- so check the firewall. For a Win7 vm on your personal system, I'd turn the firewall off completely.